# Get Min and Max values based on a Contition

Tags: elasticsearch

I have requirement that I have multiple objects in elastic search. I have to find out Min and Max values based on a condition.

Examples:

json1:

```
{
   "priceBlock":[
      {
         "CustomFilterDisplay":{
            "FilterTypeSelection":"Size",
            "FilterTypeValueText":100
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

json2:

```
{
   "priceBlock":[
      {
         "CustomFilterDisplay":{
            "FilterTypeSelection":"Size",
            "FilterTypeValueText":5
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

json3:

```
{
   "priceBlock":[
      {
         "CustomFilterDisplay":{
            "FilterTypeSelection":"Duration",
            "FilterTypeValueText":100
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

json4:

```
{
   "priceBlock":[
      {
         "CustomFilterDisplay":{
            "FilterTypeSelection":"Size",
            "FilterTypeValueText":20
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I need Min and Max values where "FilterTypeSelection" is "Size". Please suggest.

Comment: Hi, in your example, all priceBlock have just one item but it is defined as a list. Do you have multiple items in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [Filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) along with [min](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-min-aggregation.html) and [max aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html), to get the max and min values

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "t_shirts": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "priceBlock.CustomFilterDisplay.FilterTypeSelection.keyword": "Size"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min_value": {
          "min": {
            "field": "priceBlock.CustomFilterDisplay.FilterTypeValueText"
          }
        },
        "max_value": {
          "max": {
            "field": "priceBlock.CustomFilterDisplay.FilterTypeValueText"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Results will be

```
"aggregations": {
    "t_shirts": {
      "doc_count": 3,
      "min_value": {
        "value": 5.0
      },
      "max_value": {
        "value": 100.0
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Venu please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: @Venu can you please reply back to my previous comment ?